# meaning of the phrase "be on something" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have come across it in [Crash Course World History](https://youtu.be/Yocja_N5s1I). It is at around 53 second. Here it goes:

> The test will last your entire life, and it will be comprised of the millions of decisions that, when taken together, makes your life yours. And everything, everything will **be on it**.

I cannot really understand what the presenter means. Does he mean that the test will include everything, or everything will depend on the test?

Comment: Everything will be on the *test*, i.e. everything they say/teach.

Comment: For something to be **on** a test means that the test will include questions about it.  *Will irrational numbers be on the test?*  It is similar to **on the agenda**.

Comment: We usually use the preposition ***in*** rather than ***on*** in this context (Google Books claims 1,520,000 hits for [*will be **in** the test*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22will+be+in+the+test%22), but only 94,200 for [*will be **on** the test*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22will+be+on+the+test%22)).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+be+in+the+test%2Cwill+be+on+the+test&year_start=1800&year_end=2018) disagrees with you: since the 1970's "will be **on** the test" has far exceeded "will be **in** the test."  For me in North America, I've always heard **on** rather than **in**.

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether you think of tests as an immersive experience or as a roster of questions.

Comment: @Canadian Yankee, Tᴚoɯɐuo: Aguably your preference might simply reflect age and/or nationality. There weren't enough NGram hits for ***will be...*** to compare US/UK corpuses, so I switched to [***is** in/on the test*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+in+the+test%2Cis+on+the+test&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20in%20the%20test%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20on%20the%20test%3B%2Cc0). According to which ***on*** edged ahead of ***in*** in 1998 for Americans, but that hasn't happened (yet?) for Brits.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "In the test" is almost never used in standard American English. "On the test" is universally used in places I am, even by older people. The UK/US difference is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

"It" here refers to the word "test" at the beginning of the first sentence.

So, the presenter means that everything in your whole life will be on that test.